# Inequalities and continuity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

I want to prove the following

> $$|f(t_2,x_2)-f(t_1,x_1)|\le C \left(\sqrt{|t_2-t_1|+|x_2-x_1|^{2}}\right)^\alpha,$$
>   for all $t_1,t_2\in[0,T],x_1,x_2\in\Bbb{R}^d$, where $f:[0,T]\times\Bbb{R}^d\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$, $C$ a constant and $\alpha\in(0,1)$.

I know that, for all $x\in \Bbb{R}^d$, the following holds
$$
|f(t,x_2)-f(t,x_1)|\le C |x_2-x_1|^\alpha,
$$
where $t$ is fixed. In other words, $f(t,\cdot)$ is $\alpha-$Holder continuous for all $t\in[0,T]$.

I also know that for all $t\in [0,T]$
$$
|f(t_2,x)-f(t_1,x)|\le C |t_2-t_1|^{\alpha/2},
$$
where $x$ is fixed. Hence, $f(\cdot,x)$ is $\alpha/2-$Holder continuous for all $x\in \Bbb{R}^d$.

So,
\begin{align}
|f(t_2,x_2)-f(t_1,x_1)|&=|f(t_2,x_2)-f(t_2,x_1)+f(t_2,x_1)-f(t_1,x_1)|\\
&\le |f(t_2,x_2)-f(t_2,x_1)|+|f(t_2,x_1)-f(t_1,x_1)|\\
&\le C_1|x_2-x_1|^\alpha+C_2|t_2-t_1|^{\alpha/2}\\
&\le C_{max}\left(|x_2-x_1|^\alpha+|t_2-t_1|^{\alpha/2} \right).
\end{align}

How can I finish this proof? Any hints are appreciated.

I think that this inequality is necessary to conclude that the set of all bounded $\alpha$-Holder continuous in $x$ and $\alpha/2$-Holder continuous in $t$ is equal to
$$
C_b^{\alpha/2,\alpha}([0,T],\Bbb{R}^d)=\{f:[0,T]\times\Bbb{R}^d\rightarrow \Bbb{R}: f\;bounded,\;(1)\;\mbox{ and }\;(2)\;\mbox{hold}\}
$$

(1) $|f(t,x_2)-f(t,x_1)|\le C d((t,x_1),(t,x_2))^\alpha$, for all fixed $t$.

(2) $|f(t_2,x)-f(t_1,x)|\le C d((t_1,x),(t_2,x))^{\alpha/2}$, for all fixed $x$, where
$$
d((t_1,x_1),(t_2,x_2))=\sqrt{|t_2-t_1|+|x_2-x_1|^{2}}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply use
$$ a+b\le\sqrt2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
and
$$ a^\alpha+b^\alpha\le 2(a+b)^\alpha$$

Comment: So we have $ \left(\sqrt{|t_2-t_1|^\alpha+|x_2-x_1|^{2\alpha}}\right)$. How can I get $\left(\sqrt{|t_2-t_1|+|x_2-x_1|^{2}}\right)^\alpha$?

Comment: @DispN, see the update.